# Ubuntu - Internet isnt working nor popping up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I am COMPLETELY new to Ubuntu, like literally, I only know a few commands and stuff for terminal.. I recently installed it into my laptop to learn it more but for some odd reason my wifi wont pick up, nor will it accept wired connections.. Im currently running version 12.04 and I'm in dire need of assistance. I wish I could give you guys more to work with but im stoked, i have no idea how to fix this. I tried changing my interface settings(gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces) to

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

with was a method i found on google but no luck.. Can anyone help me out please????

-EDIT-

when I type `dmesg | grep -i eth` i get this

```
[    0.094674] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    0.104787] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0._OSC] (Node f5029dc8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20120320/psparse-536)
[    0.109074] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0._OSC] (Node f5029dc8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20120320/psparse-536)
[    0.109130] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0._OSC] (Node f5029dc8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20120320/psparse-536)
[    1.794527] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[   16.730616] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

and when I type `dmesg | grep -i net` i get this.

```
[    0.000000]   Transmeta GenuineTMx86
[    0.084004] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.114632] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.114633] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.114635] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
[    0.114648] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.163609] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.163898] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.163898] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.783442] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.783652] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[   16.013583] kernel BUG at include/net/cfg80211.h:2351!
[   16.419997] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   16.730616] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.261656] type=1400 audit(1371348543.594:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=669 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   20.441385] type=1400 audit(1371348546.774:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=843 comm="apparmor_parser"
```